# What is the most efficient and pythonic way to calculate (TI) over a large data set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tested a few different ways to calculate technical indicators for a large dataframe and am unsure how to determine the most efficient and pythonic way to go about it. The data is stock data (date, price, volume). The goal is to iterate through the dataframe, per ticker, calculating multiple technical indicators, and then sending the result back into the source (SQL db).

The data contains about 4,200 stock symbols with daily price data from 2000 to date (roughly 13m rows x 8 columns).

For testing, I've limited the data to just 2021 date range.
Here is a sample of the data:

```
            Date    Open    High    Low     Close Adj_close Volume  Tick
529326  2021-01-04  3270.00 3272.00 3144.02 3186.63 3186.63 4411400 AMZN
521846  2021-01-05  3166.01 3223.38 3165.06 3218.51 3218.51 2655500 AMZN
521691  2021-01-06  3146.48 3197.51 3131.16 3138.38 3138.38 4394800 AMZN
514195  2021-01-07  3157.00 3208.54 3155.00 3162.16 3162.16 3514500 AMZN
514038  2021-01-08  3180.00 3190.64 3142.20 3182.70 3182.70 3537700 AMZN
506535  2021-01-11  3148.01 3156.38 3110.00 3114.21 3114.21 3683400 AMZN
506376  2021-01-12  3120.00 3142.14 3086.00 3120.83 3120.83 3514600 AMZN
498871  2021-01-13  3128.44 3189.95 3122.08 3165.89 3165.89 3321200 AMZN
498706  2021-01-14  3167.52 3178.00 3120.59 3127.47 3127.47 3070900 AMZN
491194  2021-01-15  3123.02 3142.55 3095.17 3104.25 3104.25 4244000 AMZN
491037  2021-01-19  3107.00 3145.00 3096.00 3120.76 3120.76 3305100 AMZN
483504  2021-01-20  3181.99 3279.80 3175.00 3263.38 3263.38 5309800 AMZN
483351  2021-01-21  3293.00 3348.55 3289.57 3306.99 3306.99 4936100 AMZN
475802  2021-01-22  3304.31 3321.91 3283.16 3292.23 3292.23 2821900 AMZN
475649  2021-01-25  3328.50 3363.89 3243.15 3294.00 3294.00 3749800 AMZN
468087  2021-01-26  3296.36 3338.00 3282.87 3326.13 3326.13 2955200 AMZN
467939  2021-01-27  3341.49 3346.52 3207.08 3232.58 3232.58 4660200 AMZN
460368  2021-01-28  3235.04 3301.68 3228.69 3237.62 3237.62 3149200 AMZN
460219  2021-01-29  3230.00 3236.99 3184.55 3206.20 3206.20 4293600 AMZN
452618  2021-02-01  3242.36 3350.26 3235.03 3342.88 3342.88 4160200 AMZN
```

I'm not sure how to fully code dummy data, but here are two methods (should just need Numpy) to create random price and ticker data, I am just unsure how to merge them all into a dataframe. To simulate the same dataframe, there would be 4,200 symbols and 134 days of data.

```
letters = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',)
x=np.random.randint(500, size=(134)) # <<< generates random price
y=''.join(np.random.choice(letters) for i in range(4)) # <<< generate random 4 character string
```

Here are all the imports being used:

```
#imports
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import time
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import pyodbc
import pandas_ta as ta
import talib
```

Dataframe 'sc' is referenced, with data in the following format:

```
        Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Adj_close Volume    Tick
529377  2021-01-04  38.68   38.69   37.18   37.88   37.88   647700  ACIW
526834  2021-01-04  29.72   29.94   28.68   29.10   29.10   1527600 GOOS
526833  2021-01-04  15.35   15.40   14.92   15.01   14.39   421400  ETV
526832  2021-01-04  42.22   42.36   41.13   41.46   40.84   204000  HMN
526831  2021-01-04  13.94   15.72   13.75   15.38   15.38   880500  GATO
```

Then I want to iterate through the dataframe (which is sorted by Date) for each ticker and calculate a number of technical indicators. For now I am starting with just two moving average calculations. I've tried 3 different methods and compared the times below.

**Talib package: 10 minutes**

```
start_time = time.time()

ticks = pd.unique(sc['Tick'].tolist()) # <<< 4,200 unique tickers

ndf = [] # <<< initialize df
for tick in ticks:
    # store ID(symbol), Date, Close(adj_close), and two indicators (SMA,EMA) in variables to 
    # concat into a temporary df, and then append outside of loop. Not sure if this is most 
    # efficient/pythonic way to do this.
    ID = sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]["Tick"]
    DATE = sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]["Date"]
    CLOSE = sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]["Adj_close"]
    SMA = round(talib.SMA(sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]['Adj_close']),2)
    EMA = round(talib.EMA(sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]['Adj_close']),2)
    
    #concat into one df
    tempdf = pd.concat([ID, DATE, CLOSE, SMA, EMA], axis=1)
    
    #append into main df outside of loop
    ndf.append(tempdf)
    
    print("Completed Indicators for "+tick)
    
# Concat everything in -ndf into a flattened df (-df)
df = pd.concat(ndf)
df['t_id'] = df['Tick']+'-'+df['Date'] 
df.rename(columns={'Adj_close':'Close', 0: "SMA", 1: "EMA"},inplace=True)
df=df.sort_values(by='Date')

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
df.tail(20)
```

**Pandas TA: 13.6 minutes**

```
#Swapped the "talib" lines for Pandas-TA package
SMA5 = ta.sma(sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]['Adj_close'], length=5)
SMA15 = ta.sma(sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]['Adj_close'], length=15)
```

**Rolling method / Pandas: 14 minutes**

```
 # Swapped the "talib" lines for Rolling():
 SMA5 = sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]['Adj_close'].rolling(5,min_periods=1).mean()
 SMA15 = sc[sc["Tick"]==tick]['Adj_close'].rolling(15,min_periods=1).mean()
```

I am unsure how to gauge what an efficient time would be (is 10 minutes generally good? bad? or is it just dependent on personal requirements?) and if the approach of looping through each ticker, storing each indicator separately, then concating and finally appending back into a master daaframe is an appropriately pythonic approach. The final code will insert the complete dataframe back into a SQL table.